# Rails find with a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have seen Rails `find` method taking a block as

```
Consumer.find do |c|
  c.id == 3
end
```

Which is similar to Consumer.find(3).

What are some of the use cases where we can actually use block for a `find` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a shortcut for `.to_a.find { ... }`. Here's the method's [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.1.8/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L64):

```
def find(*args)
  if block_given?
    to_a.find(*args) { |*block_args| yield(*block_args) }
  else
    find_with_ids(*args)
  end
end
```

If you pass a block, it calls [`.to_a`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-to_a) (loading all records) and invokes [`Enumerable#find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) on the array.

In other words, it allows you to use `Enumerable#find` on a `ActiveRecord::Relation`. This can be useful if your condition can't be expressed or evaluated in SQL, e.g. querying [serialized attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html):

```
Consumer.find { |c| c.preferences[:foo] == :bar }
```

To avoid confusion, I'd prefer the more explicit version, though:

```
Consumer.all.to_a.find { |c| c.preferences[:foo] == :bar }
```

Comment: But `Consumer.to_a` isn't defined, is it? An class inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base isn't an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation.

Comment: @Dave you're right, you have to call `.all.to_a`. I should have tested my code.

Answer (score 5):

The result may be similar, but the SQL query is not similar to `Consumer.find(3)`

It is fetching all the consumers and then filtering based on the block. I cant think of a use case where this might be useful

Here is a sample query in the console

```
 consumer = Consumer.find {|c|c.id == 2}
 # Consumer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `consumers`.* FROM `consumers`
 # => #<Consumer id: 2, name: "xyz", ..>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good example of a use-case is if you have a JSON/JSONB column and don't want to get involved in the more complex JSON SQL.

```
required_item = item_collection.find do |item|
  item.jsondata['json_array_property'][index]['property'] == clause
end
```

This is useful if you can constrain the scope of the item_collection to a date-range, for example, and have a smaller set of items that require filtering further.

Comment: This is a good answer as it's the only one that has performance in mind. Without limiting the collection you will inevitably run into perf issues. It would be better to just use postgres and query jsonb directly in sql for this type of thing.