# Why did my Rails find query select all records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I ran some code along these lines:

```
MyUserModel.find([id1, id2, id3]) do |record| send_email(record) end
```

As you can see, I forgot to include `.each` after the `find`.  This seems to have resulted in `send_email` being called on **every record** in the `my_user_model` table.  I don't understand why this happened.  Can someone explain?

I'm new to ruby and rails, so I assume I'm just not understanding something about how blocks work or something like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails find with a block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055024/rails-find-with-a-block)

Comment: I don't think it's an exact duplicate, but the answer can indeed be found in the above link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing a block to `find` changes the behaviour of the method. What ends up happening is it will load all models, then return only those for which the supplied block returns `true`, not unlike how `Enumerable#find` works.

If you did something like:

```
MyUserModel.find { |m| [1,2,3].include?(m.id) }
```

Then you'd have an equivalent version, though this one is way slower since all records must be loaded rather than filtering at the database level.

Generally you'd want to write this as:

```
MyUserModel.where(id: [ 1, 2, 3 ]).each do |model|
  # ...
end
```