# Active Record query optimizations for two many-to-many join models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am displaying the following table for a Product model in Rails 4 with ActiveRecord and Postgres SQL:

[image]

Here is my ERD, where I am using a couple of many-to-many models, each arrow here represents a one-to-many relationship:

[image]

- impact_line_items are the row headings ("Total Impacts", "Source" ... etc.).
- categories are the column headings ("Greenhouse Gases", "Energy Consumptions" ... etc.)
- By adding entries to impact_line_items and categories, I can essentially extend the row and columns of the table
- product_impact_line_item represents a reference to a row of data
- impact_entry represents a cell of data

**Question:** Here is what I have in my modesl and products/show.html.erb, displaying the table.  It is making 35 queries to get each ImpactEntry, and taking a while to load.  I would like to optimize that down and looking for suggestions.

**Models:**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :product_impact_line_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :impact_line_items, through: :product_impact_line_items
  ...
end

class ProductImpactLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :impact_line_item

  has_many :impact_entries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :impact_entries

  def find_impact_entry(category)
    impact_entries.find_by_category_id(category.id)
  end

end

class ImpactEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product_impact_line_item
  belongs_to :category

end

class ImpactLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_impact_line_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :products, through: :product_impact_line_items

  validates :name, uniqueness: true

end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :impact_entries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :impact_entries
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
end
```

**View:**

```
<table id="impacts-table" class="table table-bordered table-medium">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-2"></th>
      <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
          <th class="col-md-2"><%= category.name %></th>        
      <% end %>
    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% product_impact_line_items = @product.product_impact_line_items %>
    <% product_impact_line_items.all.each do |product_impact_line_item| %>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><%= product_impact_line_item.impact_line_item.name %></th>
           <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
               <%# byebug %>
               <td class="col-md-2"> <%= product_impact_line_item.find_impact_entry(category).value %></td>
           <% end %>
        </tr>

    <% end %>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `ProductImpactLineItem.includes(:impact_line_item, :impact_entries)` instead of `ProductImpactLineItem.all` (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)
2. Change `impact_entries.find_by_category_id(category.id)` to `impact_entries.find{ |ie| ie.category_id == category.id }` so it won't call the DB each time
3. Use the [bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) to detect n+1 queries in the future

Comment: Awesome, thanks, these suggestions cut down my query time quite a bit.  For 2), is what is happening that all the impact_entires are retrieved with one query, then the block then filters it by category.id, making it more efficient?   The thread I found on this syntax, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055024/rails-find-with-a-block, the comment was there is no good use case for it, but this seems like a good one.  Actually, I don't see any special mention on perf with regards to passing in block on http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class

Comment: @frank The simple explanation is that `find_by_category_id(category.id)` or `find(id)` are ActiveRecord methods meaning it will call the DB each time. 
`find` with a block is a Ruby method and will work on the existing set (preloaded with `includes`). There is an implicit call `to_a` on that query.