# Rails, how to use a block in where statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Taken from [this stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055024/rails-find-with-a-block), one can use a block for a query, like this:

```
Consumer.find do |c|
  c.id == 3
end
```

I want to do the same with a "where" query, for example:

```
mainCustomers = Customer.where do |c|
 c.id == c.main
end
```

When I do this, I get something like this:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x0055a057444560 @scope=#<ActiveRecord::Relation
```

I can't use ActiveRecord methods, for example:

```
irb(main):013:0> mainCustomers.last
NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x0055a057444560>
```

or

```
irb(main):014:0> mainCustomers.count
NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x0055a057444560>
```

What is the correct way for using blocks in a where statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[:where](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) does not accept block condition.

You can use plain SQL, like `Customer.where('id = main')` if it works for you.

Or, you can go with more complex way... using arel tables.

```
consumer = Consumer.arel_table
Consumer.where(consumer[:id].eq(consumer[:main])).to_sql 
=> "SELECT \"consumers\".* FROM \"consumers\" WHERE \"consumers\".\"id\" = \"consumers\".\"id\""
```

Answer (score 1):

As `where` does not accept blocks but accepts hashes with array values, you may go through a two step approach to get an Activerecord collection:

```
mainCustomers_ids = Customer.select { |o| o.id == o.main }.map{ |o| o.id} 
mainCustomers = Customer.where( id: mainCustomers_ids)
```

Please remember that instead of `Customer` class you may further use any Activerecord Collection of `Customer` objects.

Comment: Would adding an index on the column you're matching on improve performance?  Seems like .select is pretty slow depending on what you're doing...

Comment: Yes, it could be slow. In my case speed was not critical so I have no idea really how to improve speed. One may look at the ultimate SQL generated in their case to see how to improve its performance.

Answer (score 0):

The StackOverflow post that you have linked to shows that the `find` used there is a shortcut for `to_a.find`. So it uses the Ruby `Array#find` method, and doesn't execute a query other than the query that retrieves all customers from the database.

Passing a block to `where` does not actually do anything. It will just return a `WhereChain`, as no argument was given. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where), `where` doesn't accept a block.

You can specify it, but it gets ignored. For example :

```
puts "abc".size do |x|
  you_can_put_anything_you_want "here"
  it is ignored anyway
end
#=> 3
```

Your code is equivalent to just :

```
mainCustomers = Customer.where
```

and using

```
Customer.where.last
```

raises the exception you mention in the question.

The syntax you mention looks like [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) :

```
Article.where{created_at >= 2.weeks.ago}
```

Squeel is a great gem, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with Rails 5.